# Native search doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I am using the latest Algolia Search WordPress plugin version 0.2.8.

When i enable **Override native search** and try to search and hit Enter, I am being redirected to the default WordPress search page `/?s=mysearchterm`.

I've set **Search index to use**: *Searchable posts*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what that option does is actually replacing the underlying search algorithm by Algolia's one -> but the look & feel (and page) will be the same.

To confirm it's using Algolia; try to search for something by including a typo in the query string:

- without Algolia, you should have 0 results
- with Algolia's default typo-tolerance, you should have results

If you want to implement the "instant-search" experience; you can follow https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/instantsearch.html